# Error while exporting to excel in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, export

I have a SharePoint 2013 list. Using jquery I have exported the data into a table and added customized code for export to excel to that particular table data. But am getting an error

> Automation server can't create object** at the line * excel = new
>   ActiveXObject('Excel.Application');

while I try to export. PFB code to export:

```
function CreateExcelSheet() {
  var i, j, str,str1,k,l,m,n,

   myTable1 = document.getElementById('project'),
            rowCount1 = myTable1.rows.length,
            excel = new ActiveXObject('Excel.Application');// Activates Excel
    excel.Workbooks.Add(); // Opens a new Workbook
    excel.Application.Visible = true; // Shows Excel on the screen
    for (i = 0; i < rowCount1; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < myTable1.rows[i].cells.length; j++) 
        //for (j = 0; j < 11; j++) 
        {
            str1 = myTable1.rows[i].cells[j].innerText;
            excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value = str1; // Writes to the sheet
            k=i;
            l=j;
        }



    }


    return;
}
```

Comment: Do someone have any idea on this?

Comment: Hello...Can somebody answer?

Comment: Going off this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157183/activex-automation-server-cant-create-object it looks like the error 'Automation server can't create object' has to do with your browser settings. Is your website added to Trusted Sites in Internet Explorer, and have you checked the ActiveX settings for Trusted Sites?

Comment: Check this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a3f7161-3581-47d1-a79c-98c0351ece38/how-to-launch-excel-application-from-client-side-javascript-?forum=netfxjscript

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you get list data in Jquery data-tables instead? it has very good look and feel and you get inbuilt buttons to export, print etc.

Just get the list data in json format using REST query and put it in datatable and use export excel, pdf etc buttons

Comment: I tried that but somehow export to excel is not working...it is exporting but it is not displaying any data